# Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger, could not connect to the database engine instance

Tags: sql-server

When I click on "Debug" in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, I get this message:

> Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger, could not connect to the database engine instance . Make sure you have enabled the debugging firewall exceptions and are using a login that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

I searched on the Internet, I followed the advice:

- run SQL Server Management Studio using Adiministrator role.
- login to the database using Windows authenticated user + sysadmin role
- Add program `ssms.exe` (SQL Server Management Studio) to the exceptions list
- Add the program `sqlservr.exe` to the exceptions list
- Add TCP port 135 to the exceptions list( server side /client side)
- Add UDP port 4500 and UDP port 500 to the exception list

But I still can't debug.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

---

I try to switch another remote SQL Server, it can work.
I guess it may possibly related to server setting, but I have any idea.

Comment: While it's technically possible, it's rarely necessary or useful to use the TSQL debugger remotely.  You really need exclusive access to the target instance, so you might as well debug on your local workstation, or RDP into the a dev server and debug there.  It's not something you want to do to a shared SQL Server, let alone a production SQL Server.